# MS Access VBA Combo Box opens a dialog instead of taking the combo box value from the form

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, combobox, dialog

I want to filter a list of records by a certain date, which the user selects from a Combo Box.

Here is the code that I have to apply a filter when the value of the combo box changes.

```
Private Sub cboSelectByDate_Change()
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Delivery Date] = Me.cboSelectByDate"
`End Sub`
```

However when the combo box is changed, a dialog box titled "Enter Parameter Value" appears asking for a value for `Me.cboSelectByDate`

How can I make sure Access reads the currently selected value of the combo box instead of opening this dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong syntax for referencing the comboBox.

```
Private Sub cboSelectByDate_Change()
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Delivery Date] = Forms!frmDeliveries!cboSelectByDate"
End Sub
```

Has the desired result